# Join 2 table and just display the active column

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have 2 tables, "table1" have 1 column to store "table2" column name. Table1 data as below:

```
 ID | Desc   | Table2ColName | Active
-------------------------------------
 1  | 1 Day  |      D1       |  Yes
 2  | 2 Days |      D2       |  No
 3  | 3 Days |      D3       |  Yes
```

Table2 data as below:

```
 ID | ShopName |  D1  | D2  | D3
----------------------------------
 1  |   Sp1    |  100 | 80  | 120
```

Then I want to join 2 table and just display the Active data, How do I using linq to query the result as below:

```
ID | ShopName |  D1  | D3
---------------------------
 1 |   Sp1    |  100 | 120
```

I have try whole day but get noting, hope can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already got the answer you needed for this, but I figured id post it anyway. Your query should look something like this.

```
var results = from a in data.table1
join b in data.table2
on a.ID equals b.ID
where a.Active =='Yes'
select new
{
a.ID,
b.ShopName,
b.D1,
b.D2
};
```